# AWS SQS, "messages in flight" how to remove those message that are in queue

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have this sqs which has some `messages in flight`, I would like to remove those message from `messages in filght` mode

Kindly help me I am clueless

Regards
Usman

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this?  Those messages have been read but have not been deleted.  This can mean that your code has a bug where it isn't dealing with messages correctly.

Comment: I believe you'll have to wait for the message visibility timeout to occur if your application failed to delete the messages for some reason, or you you can purge the queue which will delete all messages, waiting and in-flight.

Comment: thank you @MarkB and stdunbar for your time and effort. I'll review my code and come back to you guys if there is some missing parts. regards

Comment: If you know the receipt handles, you can also change the visibility timeout for the individual messages so that they become available for download quickly.